# Binding nested elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning angularjs and I barely have experience in web development, so I am not sure if i am following the right approach for the following problem.

I have this controller:

```
    function MessagesController ($scope) {
            $scope.messages = [{
                body:"This is a video",
                type:"Video",
                linkvalue:"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIR3KAfhqZQ"
            },
            {

                body:"this is an image",
                type:"Image",
                linkvalue:"http://www.dimensionsinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/Smallest-Violin.jpg"
            },
            {
                body:"this is just text",
                type:"NText",
                linkvalue: null
            }
            ];
}
```

In my view i want to pick a template based on the type of a message so I used `ng-repeat` and inside that an `ng-switch` as the following:

```
<div ng-controller="MessagesController">
    <div ng-repeat="message in messages">
        <div ng-switch on="message.type">
           <div ng-switch-when="Image">
               {{message.body}}
               <img src="message.linkvalue" width="420" height="345"/>
           </div>
           <div ng-switch-when="Video">
               {{message.body}}
               <iframe src="message.linkvalue" width="420" height="345"/>
           </div>
           <div ng-switch-when="NText">
               {{message.body}}
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is the nested elements do not get bound to the properties of the message. I guess I'm missing something.

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DT74d/

Also - I still haven't written my own directives because I need to make this thing work before i start learning how to create my own directives.

Comment: Probably not causing the problem but change `Image` to `img` after `{{message.body}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have couple of problems. One by one.

1). Use `ng-src` attributes instead `src` for images and iframes (you also should close iframe tag).

Fixed template will looks like this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="message in messages">
    <div ng-switch on="message.type">
        <div ng-switch-when="Image">
            {{message.body}}
            <img ng-src="{{message.linkvalue}}" width="420" height="345" />
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="Video">
            {{message.body}}
            <iframe ng-src="{{message.linkvalue}}" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" width="420" height="345"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="NText">{{message.body}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2). You should [whitelist](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/%24sceDelegateProvider#methods_resourceUrlWhitelist) external youtube urls in order to load them in iframe:

```
app.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        'http://www.youtube.com/embed/**'
    ]);
});
```

A note here. Not every Youtube url will load in iframe, but only those served as `http://www.youtube.com/embed/{id}`.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/z1FVZislORwl4xhQnKSH?p=preview